# replacing all values in a column with 1

Tags: dplyr, replace, na

In a dataframe, I am trying to replace all the values (except NAs) in one column with 1. I should note that the values are different dates (e.g., 02-12-2022. I would really appreciate your help?

I tried the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
data$colname[data$colname != NA] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
data$colname[!is.na(data$colname)] <- 1
```